# Angular : remove item from BehaviorSubject<any[]>([])

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

This is a little data service in my Angular5 app.
I am trying to add/remove item from an array (actually a BehaviorSubject).

`data.service.ts`

```
private roomArr_source = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
current_roomArr = this.roomArr_source.asObservable();

addRoomArr(data: any) {
    this.roomArr_source.next(this.roomArr_source.getValue().concat([data]));
}

removeRoomArr(data: any) {
    this.roomArr_source.forEach((item, index) => {
        if(item === data) { this.roomArr_source.splice(index, 1); }
    });
}
```

The addRoomArr functions works, but not the removeRommArr.
Error is :

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(item: any, index: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any[]) => void'.
error TS2339: Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>'.
```

Somehow I have to convert my BehaviorSubject into an array so that I can use .forEach().
How can i manage to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the data look like? Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung data is a simple string; thanks for sharing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using a `BehaviourSubject` then you have access to `getValue()`, so you want to splice the current value and then update the subject.

```
removeRoomArr(data: any) {
  const roomArr: any[] = this.roomArr_source.getValue();

  roomArr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item === data) { roomArr.splice(index, 1); }
  });

  this.roomArr_source.next(roomArr);
}
```

Comment: Once you use `this.roomArr_source.getValue().splice(index, 1)` the data has been changed on the source by reference so you don't appear to need to invoke `next`

Comment: If that's bad practice you could make a copy of the source using `let roomArr: any[] = [...this.roomArr_source.getValue()]` then use `this.roomArr_source.next(roomArr)`

Comment: This wasn't working for me -- `next()` wouldn't update the BehaviorSubject (Angular 8+). I suspect because it's the same array sent as next value, which isn't detected as a change. A quick workaround was to clone the array `this.roomArr_source.getValue().slice()`